# Select result set into multiple rows dynamically in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, common-table-expression, unpivot

I am having SQL Server data which contains the available and allocated information, and i need to show the report like Available Data, Alloted Data and Balance Data for each resources.

Right now I am having all the information in single row and balance data needs to be calculated. How can I retreive the expected data?

***Current Data and Output***

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2a30d/1)

**Available**

```
   +---+-------------+------------+---------------------+---------+------------+------------+
   | Id| ResourceName| EmployeeId | iGPMResourceGroupId | GroupId | Capacity01 | Capacity02 |
   +---+-------------+------------+---------------------+---------+------------+------------+
   | 1 | Palanisamy  |  24        | 1025135             | 15      |      0.70  |     0.70   |
   | 2 | Anil        |  20        | 1018707             | 15      |      1.00  |     1.00   |
   | 3 | Ravi        |  18        | 1025136             | 15      |      0.50  |     0.50   |
   | 4 | Manikumar   |   9        | 1025164             | 29      |      1.00  |     1.00   |
   | 5 | Sakathi     |  11        | 1020687             | 29      |      1.00  |     1.00   |
   +---+-------------+------------+---------------------+---------+------------+------------+
```

**Demand**

```
   +------------+-------------+---------------------+
   | Number     | ProjectName | iGPMResourceGroupId |
   +------------+-------------+---------------------+
   | BM-00000001| Project 1   | 1020687             |
   | BM-00000002| Project 2   | 1020687             |
   | BM-00000002| Project 2   | 1025136             |
   | BM-00000003| Project 3   | 1025164             |
   | BM-00000002| Project 2   | 1025135             |
   | BM-00000003| Project 3   | 1025135             |
   | BM-00000003| Project 3   | 1020687             |
   | BM-00000002| Project 2   | 1025164             |
   +------------+-------------+---------------------+
```

**Allocated**

```
  +----+---------------------+----------------+------------+---------------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
  | Id | AvailableResourceId | AssociateName  | EmployeeId | iGPMResourceGroupId | ProjectId  | Staffed01 | Staffed02 |
  +----+---------------------+----------------+------------+---------------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
  | 1  | 5                   | Sakathi        | 11         | 1020687             | BM-00000001| 0.30      |  0.30     |
  | 2  | 5                   | Sakathi        | 11         | 1020687             | BM-00000003| 0.30      |  0.30     |
  | 3  | 3                   | Ravi           | 18         | 1025136             | BM-00000002| 0.50      |  0.50     |
  +----+---------------------+----------------+------------+---------------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

**Query**

```
SELECT ResourceName, iGPMResourceGroupId, ProjectName, StaffedId, Capacity01, Capacity02, Staffed01, Staffed02          
FROM
(
    SELECT Distinct A. ResourceName, A.EmployeeId, A.[iGPMResourceGroupId], D.[ProjectName], S.[Id] AS StaffedId,  A.[Capacity01], A.[Capacity02], S.[Staffed01], S.[Staffed02]         
    FROM [AvailableR] A JOIN [DemandR] D ON A.[iGPMResourceGroupId] = D.[iGPMResourceGroupId]
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[AllocatedR] S ON A.Id = S.[AvailableResourceId] AND S.Number = D.Number AND S.[iGPMResourceGroupId] = D.[iGPMResourceGroupId]          
)X
ORDER BY EmployeeId
```

**Output**

```
+--------------+---------------------+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| ResourceName | iGPMResourceGroupId | ProjectName | StaffedId | Capacity01 | Capacity02 | Staffed01 | Staffed02 |
+--------------+---------------------+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
|      Sakathi |             1020687 |   Project 1 |         1 |          1 |          1 |         0 |         0 |
|      Sakathi |             1020687 |   Project 2 |    (null) |          1 |          1 |    (null) |    (null) |
|      Sakathi |             1020687 |   Project 3 |         2 |          1 |          1 |         0 |         0 |
|         Ravi |             1025136 |   Project 2 |         3 |          0 |          0 |         1 |         1 |
|   Palanisamy |             1025135 |   Project 2 |    (null) |          1 |          1 |    (null) |    (null) |
|   Palanisamy |             1025135 |   Project 3 |    (null) |          1 |          1 |    (null) |    (null) |
|    Manikumar |             1025164 |   Project 2 |    (null) |          1 |          1 |    (null) |    (null) |
|    Manikumar |             1025164 |   Project 3 |    (null) |          1 |          1 |    (null) |    (null) |
+--------------+---------------------+-------------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

**Expected Output:**

***Left** = Available - Sum(Allotted*)

```
+--------------+---------------------+-------------+-----------+------------+------+------+
| ResourceName | iGPMResourceGroupId | ProjectName | Status    | StaffedId  | 01   | 02   |
+--------------+---------------------+-------------+-----------+------------+------+------+
|      Sakathi |                     |             | Available | (null)     | 1    | 1    |   
|      Sakathi |             1020687 |   Project 1 | Alloted   | 1          | 0.30 | 0.30 |
|      Sakathi |             1020687 |   Project 2 | Alloted   | (null)     |(null)|(null)|
|      Sakathi |             1020687 |   Project 3 | Alloted   | 2          | 0.30 | 0.30 |
|      Sakathi |                     |             | Left      | (null)     | 0.40 | 0.40 | 
|      Ravi    |                     |             | Available | (null)     | 0.50 | 0.50 | 
|      Ravi    |             1025136 |   Project 2 | Alloted   | 3          | 0.50 | 0.50 | 
|      Ravi    |                     |             | Left      | (null)     | 0    | 0    | 
|   Palanisamy |                     |             | Available | (null)     | 1    | 1    | 
|   Palanisamy |             1025135 |   Project 2 | Alloted   | (null)     |(null)|(null)|
|   Palanisamy |             1025135 |   Project 3 | Alloted   | (null)     |(null)|(null)|
|   Palanisamy |                     |             | Left      | (null)     | 1    | 1    |
|    Manikumar |                     |             | Available | (null)     | 1    | 1    | 
|    Manikumar |             1025164 |   Project 2 | Alloted   | (null)     |(null)|(null)|
|    Manikumar |             1025164 |   Project 3 | Alloted   | (null)     |(null)|(null)|
|    Manikumar |                     |             | Left      | (null)     | 1    | 1    |
+--------------+---------------------+-------------+-----------+------------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

So, if I got you right, you need an additional column "Left" with the calculated result and a new column which stored this value per resource? I guess you can achieve this by a redesign of your query and the use of two subqueries:

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT Distinct A. ResourceName, A.EmployeeId, A.[iGPMResourceGroupId], NULL AS [ProjectName], N'Available' AS Status, NULL AS StaffedId,  A.[Capacity01], A.[Capacity02], NULL AS [Staffed01], NULL AS [Staffed02]         
    FROM [AvailableR] A
    JOIN [DemandR] D ON A.[iGPMResourceGroupId] = D.[iGPMResourceGroupId]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Distinct A. ResourceName, A.EmployeeId, A.[iGPMResourceGroupId], D.[ProjectName], N'Alloted' AS Status, S.[Id] AS StaffedId,  A.[Capacity01], A.[Capacity02], S.[Staffed01], S.[Staffed02]           
    FROM [AvailableR] A JOIN [DemandR] D ON A.[iGPMResourceGroupId] = D.[iGPMResourceGroupId]
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[AllocatedR] S ON A.Id = S.[AvailableResourceId] AND S.Number = D.Number AND S.[iGPMResourceGroupId] = D.[iGPMResourceGroupId]          
),
cteLeft AS(
SELECT ResourceName, EmployeeID, iGPMResourceGroupId, SUM([Capacity01] + [Capacity02]) - SUM(Staffed01 + Staffed02) AS LeftTotal
  FROM cte
  WHERE Status = N'Alloted'
  GROUP BY ResourceName, EmployeeID, iGPMResourceGroupId
)
SELECT *, NULL AS [Left] 
  FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT Distinct ResourceName, EmployeeId, [iGPMResourceGroupId], NULL AS [ProjectName], N'Left' AS Status, NULL AS StaffedId, NULL AS [Capacity01], NULL AS [Capacity02], NULL AS [Staffed01], NULL AS [Staffed02], [LeftTotal] AS [Left]           
  FROM cteLeft
  ORDER BY 1
```

See fiddle for details: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2a30d/16/0

Comment: Yes you are got it right but Resource **Anil** should not come as he dont have any demand.

Comment: Sure, I added the Demand Join to the query - now Anil is filtered from the result. I updated the fiddle as well

Comment: Still this is not expected result

Comment: OK, I just modified my query (haven't updated the answer yet), but while doing so I wonder: in your expected result (in the question) Manicumar is allocated in two projects, but considering your example fiddle, Manikumar isn't allocated at all - so, is the fiddle faulty ot the expected result? Here is my updated fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2a30d/25/0